# Direct sum decomposition of Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ with dense domain $D(A)$. From the continuous functional calculus, for every continuous function $f \in C(\sigma(A))$ we can associate a bounded operator $f(A)$ on $\mathscr{H}$. Moreover, if $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$, the functional:
$$\omega(f) := \langle \psi, f(A)\psi\rangle$$
is a positive linear functional, so by Riesz Representation Theorem there is an isomorphism between $\mathscr{H}$ and the set of regular Borel measures on $\sigma(A)$, denoted by $M(\sigma(A))$, such that each $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$ is uniquely associated to a measure $\mu_{\psi}$, with
$$\langle \psi, f(A)\psi\rangle = \int_{\sigma(A)}f(\lambda)d\mu_{\psi}(\lambda).$$

I now that every Borel measure $\mu$ has a decomposition $\mu = \mu_{pp}+\mu_{ac}+\mu_{sc}$, which is a consequence of the [Lebesgue Decomposition Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_of_spectrum_(functional_analysis)). Here $\mu_{pp}$ is a pure point measure, $\mu_{ac}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the usual Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mu_{sc}$ is singular with respect to the latter.

Hence, there is an identification $\psi \to \mu_{\psi} = \mu_{\psi,pp}+\mu_{\psi,ac}+\mu_{\psi,sc}$. This shows that $\mathscr{H}$ can be written as $\mathscr{H}_{pp}+\mathscr{H}_{ac}+\mathscr{H}_{sc}$, with $\mathscr{H}_{pp} := \{\psi \in \mathscr{H}: \mbox{$\mu_{\psi}$ is pure point}\}$, $\mathscr{H}_{ac} := \{\psi \in \mathscr{H}: \mbox{$\mu_{\psi}$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the usual Borel measure}\}$ and $\mathscr{H}_{sc} := \{\psi \in \mathscr{H}: \mbox{$\mu_{\psi}$ is singular with respect to the the usual Borel measure}\}$.

My question is: why this sum is actually a *direct sum*? That is, how to prove further that:
$$\mathscr{H} = \mathscr{H}_{pp}\oplus \mathscr{H}_{ac}\oplus \mathscr{H}_{sc}?$$

Comment: Doesn't it just follow from the fact that the Lebesgue decomposition is unique?  (Which, in order to ensure, you have to add the requirement that $\mu_{sc}$ is atomless.)  It should be easy to check that a measure having any two of those properties must be zero.

Comment: It's not right to call the map $\psi \mapsto \mu_\psi$ an isomorphism, since it's not linear.

Comment: Oh, or are you asking why it's an orthogonal decomposition?  It's easier to see from the Borel functional calculus, are you willing to use that?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, precisely. Why is it orthogonal? And yes, I am willing to use the Borel functional calculus if needed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easier to see from the Borel functional calculus.  In particular, for every Borel set $B$ we have a bounded, nonnegative definite operator $1_B(A)$, with the properties that:

- $1_{\mathbb{R}}(A) = I$, $1_\emptyset(A)=0$
- $1_B(A) 1_C(A) = 1_{B \cap C}(A)$
- If $B_1, B_2, \dots$ are pairwise disjoint, with $B = \bigcup_n B_n$, then $1_{B}(A) = \sum_n 1_{B_n}(A)$, with the sum converging strongly.

Now the Lebesgue decomposition can be restated as saying that for any measure $\mu = \mu_\psi$ we can partition $\mathbb{R}$ into three disjoint Borel sets $B, C, D$, such that the restrictions of $\mu$ to these three sets are respectively pure point, absolutely continuous, and singular continuous.  These restricted measures are the spectral measures associated to the vectors $\psi_{pp} = 1_B(A) \psi$, $\psi_{ac} =  1_C(A)\psi$, and $ \psi_{sc} = 1_D(A)\psi$.

Then we have
$$\psi_{pp} + \psi_{ac} + \psi_{sc} = (1_B(A) + 1_C(A) + 1_D(A)) \psi = 1_\mathbb{R}(A) \psi = \psi$$
so that $\psi$ decomposes as a sum of three vectors in the appropriate spaces.  Moreover, since the operator $1_B(A)$ is self adjoint, we have
$$\langle \psi_{pp} , \psi_{ac} \rangle = \langle 1_B(A) \psi, 1_C(A) \psi \rangle = \langle \psi, 1_B(A) 1_C(A) \psi \rangle = \langle \psi, 1_{B \cap C}(A) \psi \rangle = 0$$
because $B$ and $C$ are disjoint.  The other orthogonality relations follow similarly.

To see the spaces are closed:

- Note that a measure $\mu$ is pure point if and only if it is supported on a countable set $B$.  When $\mu = \mu_{\psi}$ this says that $\psi = 1_B(A) \psi$.  Now if $\psi_n$ is a sequence of such vectors converging to some $\psi$, with corresponding countable sets $B_n$, let $B = \bigcup_n B_n$ which is also countable.  Verify that $1_B(A) \psi_n = \psi_n$ for all $n$, and now $1_B(A)$ is a bounded operator so $1_B(A) \psi = \psi$.
- A measure $\mu$ is absolutely continuous iff $\mu(A) = 0$ whenever $m(A) = 0$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure.  When $\mu = \mu_\psi$ this simply says $1_A(B) \psi = 0$.  So if $\psi_n \to \psi$ is a sequence of such, let $A$ be an arbitrary Lebesgue null set, note $1_A(B) \psi_n = 0$ for all $n$, and since $1_A(B)$ is bounded we have $1_A(B) \psi = 0$ as well.
- A measure $\mu$ is singular continuous iff $\mu(B) = 0$ for every countable $B$ and it is supported on a set of Lebesgue measure zero.  The proof for this part follows similarly to the previous two.

Comment: Nate, thank you! This is a very nice answer! I already accepted it and will work on the details later. If any question pops up, I come back to you!

Comment: Nate, does your analysis assume that the operator $A$ has simple spectrum somehow? I followed your proof of $\mathscr{H} = \mathscr{H}_{pp}\oplus \mathscr{H}_{ac}\oplus\mathscr{H}_{sc}$ where $\mathscr{H}_{pp} = 1_{B}(A)(\mathscr{H})$ and so on, but the proof that $\mathscr{H}_{pp}$ coincides with $\{\psi: \mbox{$\mu_{\psi}$ is pure point}\}$ and so on does not seem to hold if the spectrum of $A$ is not simple. Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: What I am trying to say is the following. Suppose $\mathscr{H}_{pp} = 1_{B}(A)(\mathscr{H})$ an $\psi \in \mathscr{H}_{pp}$. I want to prove that if $\mu_{\psi}$ is pure point then $\psi \in \mathscr{H}_{pp}$. For any Borel set $E$, we have $\mu_{\psi}(E) = \langle \psi, 1_{E}(A)\psi\rangle = \langle 1_{B}(A)\psi,1_{E}(A)1_{B}(A)\psi\rangle$, but this does not prove that $\psi = 1_{B}(A)\psi$ unless the spectrum of $A$ is simple, right? This is the conclusion on your first bullet point.

Comment: @MathMath: What is the definition of "simple spectrum"?

Comment: @MathMath: Anyway, one way to see it is that $\|1_B(A)\| \le 1$, so by Cauchy-Schwarz $$|\langle \psi, 1_B(A) \psi\rangle| \le \|\psi\| \|1_B(A) \psi\| \le \|\psi\|^2.$$ On the other hand $$\langle \psi, 1_B(A)\psi \rangle = \mu_\psi(B) = \mu_\psi(\mathbb{R}) = \langle \psi,\psi\rangle = \|\psi\|^2.$$  Thus the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is equality which can only happen if $1_B(A) \psi = c \psi$ for a scalar $c$, and since $\langle \psi, c\psi\rangle = \langle \psi, \psi \rangle$ that constant must be 1.